# Filtering data from parameters c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm facing a issue when trying to search my page when trying to filter from 5 parameters.

If the parameters is null then I would want to ignore that search and only return results if there is a value in the parameters.

At the moment i used separate parameters but i need something that caters for all 5 and if it has 2 out of 4 values then it should return based on the filter.:

```
if (name != null)
{
    report = report.Where(asd => asd.name == name).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
}
else if (Id != null)
{
    report = report.Where(x => x.Id == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
}
```

So this works with only 1 in mind, how would i join all 4 together so it works together.

This is my full code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string Id = null, string name = null, string status = null, string startDate = null, string endDate = null)
{
    List<ReportModel> report = new List<ReportModel>();
    report = (from data in _context.ReportData
                //where data.Id== Id
                //&& data.name== name
                //&& data.Status == status
                //&& data.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(startDate) && data.Date < Convert.ToDateTime(endDate)
                select new ReportModel
                {
                    Id = data.Id,
                    Name = data.Plant,
                    Status = data.Status,
                    Date = data.Date
                }).ToList();

    if (name != null)
    {
        report = report.Where(asd => asd.name == name).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
    }
    else if (Id != null)
    {
        report = report.Where(x => x.Id == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
    }
    else if (status != null)
    {
        report = report.Where(x => x.Status == status).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
    }

    return Ok(report);
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Remove `else` from your `if` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about performance, do not call `ToList()` early, because it will load whole table into the memory. `IQueryable` can be combined to produce desired result.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string Id = null, string name = null, string status = null, string startDate = null, string endDate = null)
{
    var query = _context.ReportData.AsQueryable();

    if (name != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(asd => asd.name == name);
    }

    if (Id != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Id == Id);
    }

    if (status != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Status == status);
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Id);

    var report = query
        .Select(data => new ReportModel
        {
            Id = data.Id,
            Name = data.Plant,
            Status = data.Status,
            Date = data.Date
        })
        .ToList();

    return Ok(report);
}
```

Comment: You post it before me with few seconds and this is exactly the answer I wanted to propose. You have to put "new" here: data => new ReportModel

Comment: Wow that worked and code looks good. i wanted something like clean like this! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Intead of using if condition, you can add directly the condition in the Where clause

```
if (name != null)
{
    query = query.Where(asd => asd.name == name);
}
// replace by
query = query.Where(asd => asd.name == name || name == null);
```

when name will be null, the Where condition will always true.

Comment: It is working solution, but produces ineffective and big SQL.

Comment: Yes you're perfectly right